# Kruskal Wallis - Effect size

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I analyse 4 algorithms and 3 sets of metrics for each algorithm in which I apply the non-parametric Kruskal-Wallis test for each metric to detect any differences in performance between these algorithms.

I would like to know whether there is a way to calculate the effect size when applying the Kruskal-Wallis test.

As mentioned in other posts in CV, a post-hoc analysis for Kruskal-Wallis should use the Dunn's test and not the Mann-Witney test for pairwise comparisons between groups (algorithms).

By applying the "inaccurate" MW test, I can calculate the effect size, but what can I do if I apply Dunn's test?

Thanks in advance for any comment/advice.

PS: I posted this question to CV some time ago, but I didn't receive any reply yet. Hence, I post it in this forum too.

Comment: Please provide a link to the question you posted at Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0):

First, Dunn-Bonferroni tests are to be done only if the Kruskal-Wallis test indicates there are some differences among the groups.
Let's suppose you are testing at the 5% level.
Once we know there is some pattern of differences discuss, we
can try to discover what that pattern is by making pairwise
comparisons among the $g$ treatment groups.

There are $c = C(g, 2) = g(g-1)/2$ possible paired comparisons.
If we make each of these at the 5% level, there is a possibility
that the 'grand' or 'family' error probability for a pattern of differences emerging from the paired comparisons will be substantially
more than 5%.

A Bonferroni procedure is based on the Bonferroni inequality
of probability theory. In your application, the idea is that
if we test all $c$ comparisons at the level $.05/c$, then the
family error probability of the pattern cannot exceed 5%.

So if you have $g = 4$ groups, then $c = 6$ and you should
make each multiple comparison at level $.05/6 = 0.0083.$
You could use six 2-sample Wilcoxon tests at that level.
or you could look at six Wilcoxon confidence intervals for differences
in medians at confidence level $1 - 0.0083$ or 99.2%.

There is no guarantee that the pattern will be absolutely
clear. For example, if we have three levels 1, 2, and 3 in
increasing order of sample medians, it is possible you might
find a clear difference between extremes 1 and 3, but not
be able to resolve whether 2 is significantly different
from either 1 or 3.

Caveats: I wonder what you mean that you have 4 algorithms
and 3 sets of metrics. From that description, I have no
idea what your experimental design looks like. Are you
doing three separate Kruskal-Wallis tests, one for each
'set of metrics'? If so, what I have said above is OK,
with $g = 4.$

Or do you have a two factor design, in which one factor is 'algorithm' and the other is 'metric'? In that case I don't
see how a Kruskal-Wallis test can give an appropriate analysis.

If you want to say what the the factors in your design are 
and how many replications for each factor (or combination thereof),
maybe my advice would be different.

Also, I'm wondering what kind of data you have that causes you
to think in terms of nonparametric tests.

Comment: Bruce, thanks a lot for your reply. This is indeed what I am doing: Pairwise comparisons using Dunn-Bonferroni tests, only if the Kruskal-Wallis test shows significant difference. However, I think that running a 2-sample Wilcoxon test (using the Bonferronin correction) is not the same as running Dunn-Bonferroni test because the latter takes into account the pooled variance implied by the null hypothesis and retains the ranking obtained from the Kruskal-Wallis test. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: I will try to explain the experimental design more clearly: I have 4 machine learning algorithms which I test in a set of 3 problem instances of increasing difficulty. For each problem instance I calculate a metric (4 algorithms x 3 problems) and run the Kruskal-Wallis test to test the performance of the 4 algorithms per problem instance. If significant difference is found, I run pairwise comparisons using Dunn-Bonferroni test to identify the best algorithms.

Comment: Regarding your last question on selecting non-parametric tests, this is common in my area. To confirm this, however, I run before a Shapiro-Wilk's test to test whether the data follow the normal distribution and Levene's test to test for homogeneity of variance. Since, non of them holds True, I opted for using non-parametric tests.

Comment: (1) I'm still unclear whether  'problem instance' is an effect. If so KW is the wrong test. (2) KW requires groups to differ only by a shift, but pop dist'ns for groups must be of the same shape, and that implies equal variances. (3) If your number of replications per treatment is large, you may be better off with a Welsh version of standard ANOVA to adjust for heteroscedasticity. (4) What you're calling Dunn-Bonferroni may somehow use 'pooled variance', but if your variances are unequal, that information may be worse than useless. (5) I fear all of this is beyond your origl question.

Comment: Thanks Bruce again. Let me clarify what I mean. I am not a statistician; hence, the terms I use (incorrectly) might be confusing for you. With problem instance I mean an experiment where I evaluate the performance of different (4) algorithms. So, to use some statistical terms: I have 3 variables: i) algorithms (x4), (ii) problem instance (i.e., experiment x3), (iii) performance (i.e, metric) per algorithm. 
(i) and (ii) are independent, while (iii) is dependent. I run the algorithms (i) on all problem instances (ii) and measure the performance of each algorithm per problem instance (iii).

Comment: Then I run the Shapiro-Wilk's  and Lenene's test to check for normality and  homogeneity, respectively. In our area, it is common to use non-parametric tests. Hence, I use the Kruskal-Wallis test and Dunn-Bonferroni to check for significant difference and do pairwise comparisons, respectively (per (ii), the second independent variable). I hope this explanation makes sense

Comment: What is still unclear to me, is if I can (and how) calculate the effect size after running KW and DB tests.

Comment: I think you need to close this question out and start a new one in which you show an example of actual data (or similar to actual data). Then state your doubts about assumptions and ask for advice on analysis. This is like going to a doctor with a stomach ache and your _own_ diagnosis. Then quibbling about the medication.